# Trying to Scrape a Web using google import function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to get a details of a website https://uniworthshop.com/shirts.

I am looking for the information are "shirt Name", "Prices" but do not know how to add further to get the prices via import function.

Here is the sheet link.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZCrQlBjfMmO9636npMth9ErDr4kSnK8LhKb7JXS2KxU/edit#gid=0

can someone please guide or share a script to do this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the following:

- on cell A1: `=IMPORTXML("https://uniworthshop.com/shirts","//div[starts-with(@class, 'product-name')]")`
- on cell A2: `=IMPORTXML("https://uniworthshop.com/shirts","//div[@class='product-price']")`

---

#### References:

- [`IMPORTXML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en)

Comment: nabais, Thank you its working but Formula is not displaying the complete range and also there is variance in the prices.

Comment: In my sheet I checked and the all of prices match, anyway, they are not all loaded because the site has a `Load More` button in the bottom, and google sheet formulas don't have the ability to click on buttons

Comment: Can you please share a script if its possible.

Comment: No, i only do formulas in here, sorry

Comment: @Shazir if you have additional questions I would advice you to post a new question. This seems to be the complete answer for your original question.

Comment: Marios, Sure Marios i will.

Answer (score 0):

By checking that page source html, it seems that `<div class="product-name">` and `<div class="product-price">` are the two tags holding the information you need. Your best course would be to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), in this case with Python, and extract innerText from those two tags by searching elements by class, or you could just use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module to get the full html and subsequently parse it with BeautifulSoup or something else.

Comment: Nastor, Thank you for the suggestion but that will take alot time to understand it first.

Comment: Don't worry, everything takes time.